# Calculating the limit of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have two series: $$x+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^8}{4}++-\ldots\tag{1}$$
and$$x+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^4}{4}++-\ldots\tag{2}$$

(the leading coefficients are taken from the alternating harmonic series, by a rearrangement, where we take two positive terms followed by a negative one)

EDIT: I think my book intented the following series:
for example, the first series can be written in compact form as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}+\frac{x^{4n+3}}{4n+3}-\frac{x^{4n+4}}{2n+2}\right)$. I'm not definitely sure, because the author provides those expressions, but it seems reasonable to use this one. For the second, I think $4n+4$ as exponent should be replaced by $2n+2$.

We want to study the behavior of them as $x\to1^-$. Clearly the first is a power series, and since it converges for $x=1$ to the value $3/2\log(2)$ (as well as the second which however isn't a power series, rather a rearrangement), by Abel's theorem we conclude that $1)$ tends to the same limit as $x\to 1^-$. What can we say about $2)$? I'm quite sure it doesn't converge uniformly in $(a, 1)$, where $a < 1$. Is it continuous at $x=1$? Is it bounded? For me it's clear it converges pointwise for every $x$ in $[0, 1]$.

A similar question can be raised for the series $$1+\frac{1}{3^x}-\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{5^x}+\frac{1}{7^x}-\frac{1}{4^x}++-\ldots\tag{3}$$ which is not a Dirichlet series, and hence Abel's theorem does not apply. What is its limit as $x\to1^+$?
How can I approach these problems? For $2)$ I thought I could study the derivative series, but it turns out it's not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Please give the expressions of the general terms.

Comment: This is not sufficient.

Comment: It is impossible to guess the next terms.

Comment: Please show us.

Comment: Doesn't it continue $+\frac{x^9}9+\frac{x^{11}}{11}-\frac{x^6}6+\dots$?

Comment: I added an explanation. Please don't just downvote, my book writes those series in that form.

Comment: @saulspatz yes for the second I think.

Comment: Make your choice https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C2%2C5%2C7%2C4&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: I think I made it (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(2)$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac {x^n}n=\log(1+x)$$ converges absolutely on $(-1,1)$ and so may be rearranged without altering the sum.  The lit as $x\to1^-$ is then $\log2$.  It seems to me that the convergence is uniform on closed intervals in $(-1,1)$.  If we write a partial sum as the sum of the odd terms plus the sum of the even terms, we have the sum of two partial sums of power series, both of which converge uniformly.

I don't know how to deal with the Dirichlet seies.

Comment: Yes, indeed in closed intervals. But I wasnt sure in $(0, 1)$ open

Comment: I think you mean (-1, 1) btw

Comment: @Peanut Yes, $(-1,1)$ of course.  Thanks.

Comment: I think we can use a similar argument for the dirichlet series and consider the dirichlet eta function?

Comment: Well, in the domain of absolute convergence you can use a similar argument.  I don't really remember anything about Dirichlet series, sad to say.

Comment: I think I can use the fact that the eta function has a sum $<1$ for every $x > 0$. Since $3/2\ln(2) > 1$, it should be enough to say that it is not continuous.

Comment: Ok I think we can say the limit is $\ln(2)$. Because by the same reasoning we can rearrange it to the dirichlet eta function for $x > 1$. Then this series is uniformly convergent in any interval $[\epsilon, +\infty)$. Hence we can apply limit term by term and obtain $\ln(2)$ as well. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: @Peanut I don't know.  As I said before, I really don't remember anything about Dirichlet series.  You may want to ask another question.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks a lot for your time!